# Increase variable x amount every x seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

l am working on a mobile endless running game on unity.My character's speed is equal to a var called "speed":

```
var speed = 7;
GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = new Vector3 (0, 0, speed);
```

and l want that var (speed) to increase by 4 every 30 seconds using C#. Any ideas?

Comment: Code speaks better than plain requirement. Please let us know your approach and SO contributors will try to solve that in better way .

Comment: Learn about [courotines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), you can create a timer with them. if you have issues after trying your own code, show them here.

Comment: In C# you can use timer and set interval you can simply do this. But i believe you should do in unity perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this in Unity.

**1**.In the `Update` function with `Time.deltaTime` by using it to increment a variable

```
int speed = 7;

float counter = 0;
void Update()
{
    //Increment Counter
    counter += Time.deltaTime;

    if (counter >= 30)
    {
        //Increment Speed by 4
        incrementSpeed();

        //RESET Counter
        counter = 0;
    }
}


void incrementSpeed()
{
    speed += 4;
}
```

**2**.With coroutine and `WaitForSeconds` or `WaitForSecondsRealtime`.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(incremental());
}

IEnumerator incremental()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Wait for 30 seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(30);

        //Increment Speed
        incrementSpeed();
    }

}

void incrementSpeed()
{
    speed += 4;
}
```

Which one to use really depends on if you want to see the counter or not. With the second solution, you can't see the status of the timer. It will just increment after every 30 seconds. These are the most basic ways.

Comment: Your first way is more performance. because second one create a new coroutine that works parallel with your update and there is no need to use second one for this issue.

Comment: @BlackMB That's right but it shouldn't be a problem because you can create `WaitForSeconds` outside the while loop or outside the function then use it in the while loop. It will remove the allocation.

Comment: It will, but you better don't create it when you want to remove it. Its not a problem, i give you upvote, i only said that first way is more performant buddy.

Comment: I would add InvokeRepeating("incrementSpeed", 30,30); to your answer.

Comment: I stay away from recommending the use of reflections to new Unity users unless that's the only option. When answering people's question. You will hardly see my answer recommending `SendMessage`, `Invoke` and `InvokeRepeating`. Yes, they are part of the official API but should be avoided.